# sql server 2008 case statement in where clause not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 table, `Documents`, `SR` and `events`

In `documents` I am saving all documents related to SR and Events.

And I want to show all documents in one page.

So I am using this select query

```
Select * 
from documents d, SR s, Events e 
where d.relationid = ( case d.documenttype when 'SR' the s.SRId else 'e.eventid end)
```

but it's not working.

My `document` table structure is like this :

```
documentid int, 
documenttype nvarchar(50),
relationid int,
document image,
docdate date
```

Can anyone please point me to my mistake ?

I want to select all documents with related info. means if its SR document than SR details should display otherwise Events. There is only 2 types of documents right now.

What should be my select query for this ?

Comment: what are the columns for `SR` and `EVents`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join then using `LEFT JOIN`,

```
SELECT  d.*,
        COALESCE(s.Col1, e.Col1) AS Col1,
        COALESCE(s.Col2, e.Col2) AS Col2,
        COALESCE(s.Col3, e.Col3) AS Col3,
        COALESCE(s.Col4, e.Col4) AS Col4
FROM    documents d
        LEFT JOIN SR s
            ON d.relationID = d.SRID
        LEFT JOIN Events e
            ON d.relationID = e.eventID
```

where `Col1,...., Col4` are the columns of each table youw ant to be displayed based on `documenttype`.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

The more safe version of the query above assuming that the same ID can contain on `SR` and `Events` table would be by using `CASE()`

```
SELECT  d.*,
        CASE WHEN d.documenttype = 'SR' THEN s.Col1 ELSE e.Col1 END) AS Col1,
        CASE WHEN d.documenttype = 'SR' THEN s.Col2 ELSE e.Col2 END) AS Col2,
        CASE WHEN d.documenttype = 'SR' THEN s.Col3 ELSE e.Col3 END) AS Col3,
        CASE WHEN d.documenttype = 'SR' THEN s.Col4 ELSE e.Col4 END) AS Col4
FROM    documents d
        LEFT JOIN SR s
            ON d.relationID = d.SRID
        LEFT JOIN Events e
            ON d.relationID = e.eventID
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN SR.DocumentType = 'SR' THEN s.SRid ELSE e.eventId END AS Id
FROM documents d
LEFT JOIN SR s
ON s.SRId = d.relationId
LEFT JOIN Events e
ON e.EventId = d.relationId
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Select * 
from documents d
    left join SR s on d.relationid = d.SRId
    left join Events e on d.relationid = e.eventid
where d.relationid = ( case when d.documenttype = 'SR' then s.SRId else e.eventid end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to write Where clause as you need all records

Below Query Works for sure

```
Select DocumentID,
       DocumentType,
       RelationID,
       case when DocumentType = 'SR' then S.SRID else E.EventID end as Doc_DataID
From 
      Documents D
Left outer join SR S on D.RelationID = S.SRID
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENTS E on E.EventiD = D.RelationID
```