# How to get desired result from this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have problem similar to my this question :
[sql server 2008 case statement in where clause not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118306/sql-server-2008-case-statement-in-where-clause-not-working)

I have same document,SR and event table.

My document table structure is like this :

```
documentid int, 
documenttype nvarchar(50),
relationid int,
document image,
docdate date
```

and SR table structure :

```
SRId int,
CustomerId int, ( related to customer table)
SRdetail,
SRDate
```

and Event Table :

```
EventId int,
SRId int, (related to SR table)
Event,
EventDate
```

I got all the rows properly with this query :

```
Select * 
from documents d 
left join SR s on d.relationid = s.SRId 
left join Events e on d.relationid = e.EventId
```

But I have to do filtration also. like I need to display all documents by customer.

So I am performing query for this like this :

```
 Select * 
 from documents d 
 left join SR s on d.relationid = s.SRId 
 left join Events e on d.relationid = e.EventId 
 where (s.CustomerId = 123 or 
        e.SRId in (select SRId from SR where CustomerId = 123))
```

But its not giving me proper output. its displaying some of the records of diff customer's events and that customer's SR. means its not filtering properly.

I did try with 'and' instead of 'or' but with 'and' its displaying only some records.

Am I wrong somewhere in query ?

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Select * 
 from documents d 
 left join SR s on d.relationid = s.SRId 
 left join Events e on d.relationid = e.EventId 
 where (s.CustomerId = 123 or e.SRID=s.SRID) . Left join will fetch the not matching records from opposite table.<br>              Select * 
 from documents d 
 inner join SR s on d.relationid = s.SRId 
 inner join Events e on d.relationid = e.EventId 
 where (s.CustomerId = 123 or e.SRID=s.SRID)                                                       // or will fetch customerid's equal in both SR and Events table.

Comment: Thanks Kumar. But still its not working. and e.SRID=s.SRID cond will always match. i want to match the SRID with e.SRID who has Customerid 123

Comment: Try this  (s.CustomerId = 123 or (e.SRID=s.SRID and s.customerid=123) )

Comment: It still not working kumar. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem got solved.

I create one view with the use of all 3 tables and of this query :

```
  Select * from documents d left join SR s on d.relationid = s.SRId left join Events e on d.relationid = e.EventId
```

and than i am using where condition on that view to filter data by customer.

Thanks a lot everyone for helping me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change left join to inner join
when you want to filter data, filter on a left join would not do anything

```
Select * 
from documents d 
left join SR s on d.relationid = s.SRId and d.documenttype = 'sr'
left join Events e on d.relationid = e.EventId and d.documenttype = 'event'
where s.CustomerId = 123 or 
      e.SRId in (select SRId from SR where CustomerId = 123)
```

Comment: what result are you actually expecting?

Comment: i want to get all the documents which are of particular customer. like customer 123

Comment: @Mausami : Removing the or condition will give you the expected result.

Comment: and what did you get by running the query with inner join? does it miss any data, or return more data, and what data is missing or should not be returned?

Comment: you can update you question with some sample data, result you got, and result you want. those information will be really useful to people who would like to help you

Comment: its returning all customer data and some of the 123 customer data is missing.

Comment: I want just all data of one customer only.

Comment: first of all, the data relation looks bit odd. why relationid is foreign key for two tables? should there be SRID, and EventId in document table? or documentid in both SR and Event Table. if there a SR which SRID is 1, will its related Event's EventID is 1 as well?

In your data structure, RelationID means two things, a SR or an Event. but in a ER model, it should only represent one entity

I feel like we are looking at a issue which more related to data structure rather than just sql query syntax

Comment: for example. will there be a SR which's CustomerID is 123, and SRID is 1, and there is a Event which's EventID is 1, but this Event has nothing to do with customer 123? if this is the case, the query will return documents which's relationid is linked to Event(id = 1), but if you make RelationID into two columns, SRID and EventID, then you wont have this issue

Comment: No. I think i couldn't explain you properly. There is SR table which has customerid related to each Service request. and there is event table which has SRID related to each event. and there is document table in which i am storing all docs related to SR or Event. and In document table i have document type field which determine whether that doc is of SR or Event. and by documenttype the relationid will be determined like id documenttype is 'SR' than relation is is SRId otherwise its Eventid likewise.

Comment: and now i want to display all documents of SR and Event related to particular customer.

Comment: get you now~ check the answer, hopefully, it will work. when you make a join to SR or Event, need to include DocumentType as well as it is the part of the relation

Answer (score 0):

> and e.SRID=s.SRID cond will always match

On this above comment, what I guess is:

```
Select * from documents d 
left join SR s on d.relationid = s.SRId 
left join Events e 
on d.relationid = e.EventId 
where 
(s.CustomerId = 123 AND e.SRID=s.SRID)
```

Comment: e.SRID=s.SRID is already matched. I want to match e.SRID in (select SRID from SR where Customerid = 123)

Comment: can you please provide us some example in sqlfiddle.com with data?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select * 
from documents d 
left join SR s on d.relationid = s.SRId and s.CustomerId = 123
left join Events e 
     join SR se on e.SRId = se.SRId and se.CustomerId = 123
on d.relationid = e.EventId 
where coalesce(s.CustomerId, se.CustomerId) = 123
```